# Determine angular route with data

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to determine the current route & change the components accordingly. I'm using this approach.

**my.component.ts**

```
...
constructor(public router: Router){}
...
```

**my.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="router.url != '/print'">
    <h2>Not in print page!</h2>
</div>
```

This works fine but when i change the route to accept some data i.e. id this fails.

**my route**

```
{path: 'print/:id', component: PrintComponent }
```

How to solve this?

Comment: use .includes function. i.e. div *ngIf="!router.url.includes('/print') .. not in print page.

Comment: @NirajPaudel thanks!! Works like a charm

Comment: I think  route data is better that check the url

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
constructor (public route: ActivatedRoute){}
```

Now you can call this:

```
route.snapshot.url[0].path
```

The result here should then always be "print".

Answer (score 0):

You can add a data object to each route and check base on the data value like

```
{path: 'print/:id', component: PrintComponent , data:{isPrint:true} }
```

and you can use  to get the route data like this

```
this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data
this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(...)
```